# patchValue doesn't set the value to custom component

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form using a custom component. This component is implementing `ControlValueAccessor` using provider `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR`.

When saving this form using this component, I can get its value (which is an object with several properties).
Now, I want to load this form using existing data using `this.form.patchValue(myObj)`.
Standard fields like `input` get their values correctly but my custom component doesn't seems to "receive" thoses values.

How to use patchValue with a custom component ?

Here is my component code (relevent part) :

```
 import { Component, ElementRef, forwardRef, Input, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
 import { AbstractControl, ControlValueAccessor, FormControl, FormGroup, NG_VALIDATORS, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, ValidationErrors, Validator, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
 
 
 @Component({
   selector: 'party-identifier-selector',
   templateUrl: './party-identifier-selector.component.html',
   styleUrls: ["./party-identifier.component.scss"],
   providers: [
     {
       provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
       multi: true,
       useExisting: forwardRef(() => PartyIdentifierSelectorComponent)
     },
     {
       provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
       multi: true,
       useExisting: forwardRef(() => PartyIdentifierSelectorComponent)
     }
   ]
 })
 export class PartyIdentifierSelectorComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor, Validator {
 
   @ViewChild('txtArea') txtArea: ElementRef;
 
   @Input()
   lettersAllowed: string = "None,A,B,C,D";
   @Input()
   defaultLetter: string = "";
   @Input()
   border: string = "false";
   
   value: IPartyIdentifier;
 
   countries = COUNTRIES;
 
   letterSelected: string = "";
   form: FormGroup;
   touched: boolean = false;
   disabled: boolean = false;
   invalid: boolean = false;
   addressType: "STRUCT" | "UNSTRUCT";
 
   onChange = (value: IPartyIdentifier) => { return value; };
 
   onTouched = () => { };
   onValidatorChange = () => { };
 
   ngOnInit() {
     this.letterSelected = this.defaultLetter;
     if (this.letterSelected == "")
       this.letterSelected = this.lettersAllowed.split(",")[0];
     if (this.value != undefined)
       this.letterSelected = this.value!.letter;
     this.addressType = "STRUCT";
 
     this.form = new FormGroup({
       letter: new FormControl(this.letterSelected),
       account: new FormControl('', Validators.pattern("^[\\sÀ-ÿ\\w\\-_\\.,:]*$")),
       partyIdentifier: new FormControl('', Validators.pattern("^[\\sÀ-ÿ\\w\\-_\\.,:]*$")),
       bic: new FormControl('', Validators.pattern("^[A-Z0-9]{8}([A-Z0-9]{3})?$")),
       location: new FormControl('', Validators.pattern("^[\\sÀ-ÿ\\w\\-_\\.,:]*$")),
       name: new FormControl('', Validators.pattern("^[\\sÀ-ÿ\\w\\-_\\.,:]*$")),
       unstructuredAddress: new FormControl('', Validators.pattern("^[\\sÀ-ÿ\\w\\-_\\.,:]*$")),
       addressLine1: new FormControl('', Validators.pattern("^[\\sÀ-ÿ\\w\\-_\\.,:]*$")),
       addressLine2: new FormControl('', Validators.pattern("^[\\sÀ-ÿ\\w\\-_\\.,:]*$")),
       postCode: new FormControl('', Validators.pattern("^[\\sÀ-ÿ\\w\\-_\\.,:]*$")),
       townName: new FormControl('', Validators.pattern("^[\\sÀ-ÿ\\w\\-_\\.,:]*$")),
       country: new FormControl()
     },
       { updateOn: 'change' });
     this.form.valueChanges.subscribe((_) => {
       this.setOutputValue();
     });
 
   }
 
   setOutputValue() {
     let value = this.form.value;
     //Generate output value
    ...
     this.onChange(this.value);
   }
 
   markAsTouched() {
     if (!this.touched) {
       this.touched = true;
       this.onTouched();
     }
   }
 
   writeValue(value: IPartyIdentifier) {
     this.value = value;
   }
 
   registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
     this.onChange = fn;
   }
 
   registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
     this.onTouched = fn;
   }
   setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
     this.disabled = isDisabled;
   }
 
   validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
     var controlValue = control.value as string;
     var regEx = new RegExp(("^[\\sÀ-ÿ\\w\\-_\\.,:]*$"));
     this.invalid = !regEx.test(controlValue);
     if (controlValue != undefined && controlValue.length > 0 && this.invalid)
       return { invalidTextInput: true };
     else
       return null;
   }
 
   registerOnValidatorChange?(fn: () => void): void {
     this.onValidatorChange = fn;
   }
 }
```

Comment: `writeValue` gets called when `patchValue` called so you'll need to patch this to your internal form.

Comment: Thank you. It works better now :D

Comment: Don't forget to unsubscribe `this.form.valueChanges`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Andrew's answer, I was able to solve this.
In `writeValue` function, I had to do an inner `patchValue`.